# Sampling random from global data object, and using in input choices in r Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This feels like a really simple question that I just cannot get my head around.
Essentially I have an app where I have a pre-existing data object (a list of choices) from which I am sampling randomly. I am then using this information for input choices on the UI. The choices from these are then downloaded as a csv file later. Some of the practicality may not make sense here, this example is just for illustration. Here is a reprex:

**UI**

```
library(shinyWidgets)

sides <- c("Right", "Left", "Up", "Down") # list of possible choices
sides <- rep(sides,2)
side_tested <- sample(sides,8) # random sample of 8

ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
 downloadButton("dlData","Download")
),
mainPanel(
radioGroupButtons(
       inputId = "ad1",
       label = "Correct",
       choices = c(side_tested[1], "Yes", "No"), # takes the first value in side_tested list
       justified = TRUE
     ),
     radioGroupButtons(
       inputId = "ad2",
       label = NULL, 
       choices = c(side_tested[2], "Yes", "No"), # takes the second value in side_tested list etc etc
       justified = TRUE
     ), 
# note I will have 8 input buttons in the final example matching length of side_tested, keeping short for reprex.
)
)
)
```

**Server**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
ad_results <- reactive({
c(input$ad1, input$ad2)
})

results <- reactive({
    data.frame(cbind(side_tested,ad_results()))
  })

output$dlData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = ("Results.csv"),
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(results(), file, row.names=TRUE)
    })

}
```

My problems are:

- when publishing this app the sample is not random on each launch of the app (i.e. the choices are the same each time you load the app). My understanding for this is because `side_tested` is in the global environment and is not being sampled each time.

I have tried adding the sampling into the server and ui but cannot get it to work. One almost solution I had was making the ui a function with help from [this idea](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1882) like this

```
ui <- function(req) { 
side_tested <- sample(sides,8)
# ... rest of app here
```

- Which solved the randomizing problem but then my download button no longer works.

If anyone could help please to point me in the right direction, that would be great!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to sample on the server side and use `updateRadioGroupButtons()`.  Perhaps this will meet your needs.

```
library(shinyWidgets)

sides <- c("Right", "Left", "Up", "Down") # list of possible choices
sides <- rep(sides,22)
# side_tested <- sample(sides,8) # random sample of 8

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton("dlData","Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      
      radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = "ad1",
        label = "Correct",
        choices = c("Yes", "No"), # takes the first value in side_tested list
        justified = TRUE
      ),
      radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = "ad2",
        label = NULL, 
        choices = c("Yes", "No"), # takes the second value in side_tested list etc etc
        justified = TRUE
      ) 
      # note I will have 8 input buttons in the final example matching length of side_tested, keeping short for reprex.
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  side_tested <- sample(sides,8) # random sample of 8
  
  updateRadioGroupButtons(session, "ad1", choices = c(side_tested[1], "Yes", "No"))
  updateRadioGroupButtons(session, "ad2", choices = c(side_tested[2], "Yes", "No"))
  
  
  
  ad_results <- reactive({
    c(input$ad1, input$ad2)
  })
  
  results <- reactive({
    data.frame(cbind(side_tested,ad_results()))
  })
  
  output$dlData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = ("Results.csv"),
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(results(), file, row.names=TRUE)
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```